# how to add external link in laravel dom pdf version 0.7.0

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, hyperlink, dompdf

```
<a href="{!! route('qc-question-detail',[$question->qc_po_style_id.'-'.$question->qc_po_style_report_section_question->object_question_id.'-'.$question->qc_po_style_report_section_question->object_question_type]) !!}" >VIEW</a>
```

> this is how I add a link into my blade file but it is not clickable.

`laravel` version 5.3.31

`dompdf` version 0.7.0.